# CBCentralManager: how to determine which peripheral is the manager scanning for

Tags: ios, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

I am wondering how to determine which peripherals a CBCentralManager is scanning for **without using additional variables**, in other words only from the CBCentralManager object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only useful API from CBCentralManager, [`retrievePeripherals:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/retrievePeripherals:) was totally removed as of iOS 9.  My guess Apple did this because of some fuzzy security concern (e.g. malicious software scanning for Bluetooth devices to exploit?).

The replacement within CBCentralManager, [`retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:) requires a list of device identifiers already known to the app.